# How do I surround a line with quotes on bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

When I run `for i in $(find -name '*.ogg'); do echo '$i'; done` I don't get one line per file as I expected. Instead, when a file name has a space in it, each word comes out in a separate line, so I can't run commands on the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find -name '*.ogg' -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 command
```

Comment: Yep, use `-print0` to make find use the null character as a result separator instead of CR.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know about xargs. It's like `map` for the command line :) Thanks!

Comment: From `man xargs`: `-L max-lines Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of maybe what you want to do:

```
 #! /bin/sh
 IFS="\n"
 for xxx in `cat /etc/hosts`
 do
    echo $xxx
 done
 exit 0
```

I.E: Change the IFS (Inter Field Seperator) to \n instead of space,tab,\n

Answer (score 0):

You should pipe `find` into a `while` loop instead:

```
find -name '*.ogg' | while read -r i; do echo "$i"; done
```

Also, the single quotes you had around `$i` would prevent the variable from being expanded to its value.

Another way is to use process substitution:

```
 while read -r i; do echo "$i"; done < <(find -name '*.ogg')
```

which has the advantage of not creating a subshell out of the `while` loop, so variables set (and other changes to the environment) inside the loop be available after the loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the command in parallel and if have GNU Parallel http:// www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
find -name '*.ogg' | parallel do_stuff {} --options otherargs
```

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 0):

Also there is no need in `find` in this case. You may set `globstar` option and use bash globbing.

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.ogg; do echo '$i'; done
```